# how to derive CPU registers information in each tasks in linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

I have the pointer to the task struct for each tasks inside the Linux kernel, now how do I derive the CPU registers value (eax, or rax) for each tasks, assuming that the tasks is now not running?

Answer (score 3):

task_pt_regs(task) provides a pointer to the block of saved registers. They are always located at the top of the task's kernel stack area. The kernel stack area is essentially "empty" while the task is executing. When a system call is executed (or the kernel is entered for other reasons), the "system entry" code is executed (for x86 this is in arch/x86/kernel/entry_{32,64}.S). The pt_regs structure is constructed to match the order of register saves done in the entry code.

Answer (score 0):

In task_struct structure there is field called thread_struct. You can use that to get CPU specific state.

```
/* CPU-specific state of this task */
        struct thread_struct thread;
```

Comment: I found that too, but thread_struct (if u look up the definition) does not have "eax" or many other registers, but "ip", and "gs", un-conventionally named, and that is only for 32-bit, in 64-bit it is impossible to derive the RIP? or RAX?